# Why is jQuery .click() is skipped over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a small script of javascript which iterates over a set of checkboxes which grabs the name attribute and value and then convert it to json.  Then I use that value to set the href of an  element and then try to trigger a click.

For some reason everything seems to function properly except for the click.  I successfully change the href, I console.log() a value before the .click() and after.  Everything hits except for the click.  The url in the href is value as I clicked it manually.

I have my script included just before the closing body tag and have it wrapped in `$(document).ready()`. and I do not have duplicate ID's (I viewed the rendered source to check)

Can anyone offer some insight on this?

Here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#multiExport" ).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var i = 0;
        var list = new Array();

        $('.appSelect:checked').each(function(){
           var name = $(this).attr('name');
           var id = $(this).val();
           list[i] = new Array(name, id);
           i++;
        });

        var serList = JSON.stringify(list);
        console.log(serList);

        var webRoot = $("#webRoot").text();
        $("#exportLink").attr('href', webRoot+"/admin/admin_export_multiExport.php?emailList="+serList); //hits

        console.log('1'); //hits
        $("#exportLink").click(); //this line never executes
        console.log('2'); //hits

    });

});
```

Comment: Are you expecting the console to say `1`, then `hey`, then `2`?

Comment: No, I edited the code, I need the line `$("#exportLink").click();` to execute but it seems to be skipped over.  I console 1, then 2, but no click or error.

Comment: What gives you: `console.log($("#exportLink").length);`

Comment: I get a 1 printed to the console in addition to what was there. So 1, 1, 2

Comment: But to trigger DOM node click method, you need: `$("#exportLink")[0].click();`

Comment: How do you know it isn't executing? What is supposed to happen when you click that link? What happens when you click it with the mouse?

Comment: @A.Wolff `$().click()` works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/sFQNP/

Comment: @JasonP not for anchor tag with href if OP wants to simulate user click. See not working: http://jsfiddle.net/MWa28/  Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/MWa28/1/

Comment: When I click it with a mouse I get sent to the intended page. I also hit both console.log() before AND after.

Comment: @d.lanza38 so use that: `$("#exportLink")[0].click();` or `$("#exportLink").get(0).click();` or `document.getElementById('exportLink').click()` or dispatchEvent or etc... This is not jQuery click handler you want to call but native DOM click method

Comment: @A.Wolff adding the [0] causes it to work.  I guess it's treating it as an array event though there is a single element.  Post an answer and I will accept.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @d.lanza38 nothing to do with array but with DOM node, please consider to accept Kevin B's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(selector).click()` won't actually follow the link the way clicking on it with your mouse will. If that's what you want, you should unwrap the jquery object from the element.

```
$(selector)[0].click();
```

Otherwise, all you're doing is triggering event handlers that may or may not exist.

Comment: I am very surprised. Why would .click() on the jQuery object not trigger the following of the link?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that's how it has always been. .submit on the other hand does result in the form submitting, same with other events like focus and blur.

Answer (score 2):

I may guess you need

```
$(document).on('click', '#multiExport', function(e){
```

(you can replace document by a nearest element, if you got one).

if you need dynamic click event binding.

EDIT

I would try something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#exportLink").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
    $("#multiExport" ).on('click', function(e){
        //whatever you want
        $('#exportLink').attr('href', 'something').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: But that all gets triggered perfectly fine.  I run through all of the code, it just seems to skip over or ignore the `$("#exportLink").click();` bit.

Comment: @d.lanza38 ok, was just a guess, see edit maybe, then ?

Comment: I don't need to bind an action to `$("#exportLink")`, I added that bit as part of debugging, I edited the code in the OP to reflect.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

> $("#exportLink").click(); // this would launch the event.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I am very surprised that the .click() does not work.

If the idea is to load the page, then the alternative is

```
$(function() {
  $("#multiExport" ).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var list = [];

    $('.appSelect:checked').each(function(){
       var name = $(this).attr('name');
       var val = $(this).val();
       list.push([name, val]);
    });

    var serList = JSON.stringify(list);

    var webRoot = $("#webRoot").text();
    location=webRoot+"/admin/admin_export_multiExport.php?emailList="+serList;
  });
});
```